# Is there any way to fix the login page not found error?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I created a login page, but it seems that the link is not valid, I have tried many ways but it doesn't work
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    [http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%25url%20'login'%7D](http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%25url%20%27login%27%7D)
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls

Here is my code

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact' ),
    path('register/', views.register, name= 'register'),
    path( 'login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="pages/login.html"), name="login"),
    path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'),name='logout'),
   
]
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset ="UFT=8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> Documment</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method = "POST" >
        {%csrf_token%}
        {%for key, value in form.errors.items %}
            {{value }}
        {% endfor %}
        <p> <label>Tài Khoản : </label>{{form.username}}</p>
        <p> <label>Mật Khẩu : </label>{{form.password}}</p>
        <input type="hidden" name='next' value="/"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Đăng nhập"/>


    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share full traceback?

Comment: Can you add your settings file? Login URL should be set somewhere in settings or in the middleware. Can you share whatever is relevant. It looks like you might be using `reverse` where it should not be used.

Comment: plz add the code of your class-based view

Comment: make sure that login.html template must be inside pages folder

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I fixed the error. I forgot to call in views.py so this error occurs